# jquery form plugin does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I am a newbie programmer. I have been stuck for two days with a simple coding problem.I try to use jquery form plugin for submitting a form to another page and get feedback from that page.The problem is the plugin is not working, the form is submitted normally without feedback. Here is the code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<div id='preview'></div>
<form  action='ajaxcall.php' id='upload_pic' enctype='multipart/form-data'  method='post'>
<input type='file' id='pic' name='picture'>
<input type='submit' id='sub'>
</form>

var options=
{
  target:'#preview',
  url:'ajaxcall.php'
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sub").click(function(){
        $('#preview').html("<img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Loading.....'/>");
        $('#upload_pic').ajaxForm(options).submit();
    });
});
```

Here is my ajaxcall.php page code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['size']))
{
 echo "<img src='images/197.jpg'>";
}
```

Expectation was the echoed image would feedback but the page is simply redirected to ajaxcall.php page.I understand that ajaxForm() function is not working. The same question I am asking two times in SO, but still no satisfactory solution. But why? Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of size, error might be a better 'validator' on the server side http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0):

Use adeneo's answer, because I also do not see why you would use this plugin, but here could be a few reasons why what you have isn't working:

In the examples from [the plugin's website](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#html), you should

1. bind to the form, not the button
2. use the beforeSubmit option
3. Remove the submit() from the end of your call, not sure why it is
   there
4. Watch console for any errors

> ```
> var options=
> {
>   target:'#preview',
>   url:'ajaxcall.php',
>   beforeSubmit:  showLoading,
>   error: function(e){
>       alert("Error: " + e);
>   }
> };
>
> function showLoading(){
>     $('#preview').html("<img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Loading.....'/>");
> }
>
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $("#upload_pic").ajaxForm(options);
> });
> ```

Comment: not working.please help.if your code work my code will work.whats the problem.feeling desperate...

Comment: I've updated answer, but you should really use adeneo's answer. If you cannot get that to work, then you're not going to get this to work either. You need to troubleshoot what is going wrong, it's pretty difficult for us to guess. Use console, debugger, and alerts to figure out where things are going wrong.